# Gravar Array de Email e Telefone no Banco de dados com Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Preciso gravar um array html de `telefones` e `Emails`, no banco de dados, mas não estou sabendo como receber tais dados. O Número de telefone e email pode ser `0 ou N`, como na imagem a seguir, a pessoa pode adicionar quantos input quiserem.

Então precisava conseguir receber os dados, para poder inserir no banco `("Essa parte eu sei")`, só não estou conseguindo receber, pois o meu model sempre chega `vazio`, nos campos de telefone:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esse é meu `script` que duplica os input

```
CloneTelephone = function () {
    var cloneTel = $('#dynamicDivTel');

    $(document).on('click', '#addTel', function () {
        $('<span>' +
            '<label class="form-control-label" for="">Telefone ou Celular</label>' +
            '<div class="input-group form-group">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">' +
            '<div class="input-group-append">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="delTel"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</span>').appendTo(cloneTel);
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#delTel', function () {
        $(this).parents('span').remove();
        return false;
    });

}(),
```

Esse é a parte do meu `form`:

```
<div class="pl-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" id="dynamicDivTel">
            <label class="form-control-label" asp-for="Phones">Telefone ou Celular</label>
            <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control phone" asp-for="Phones" placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addTel"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Phones" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" id="dynamicDivEmail">
            <label class="form-control-label" asp-for="Emails">Email</label>
            <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" asp-for="Emails" placeholder="Email">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addEmail"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Emails" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E esse é meu `ViewModel`:

```
public class AddCondominiumViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é um campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome Fantasia é um campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome Fantasia")]
    public String FantasyName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNPJ é um campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{2,3}.?\d{3}.?\d{3}/?\d{4}-?\d{2}", ErrorMessage = "CNPJ está em um formato inválido.")]
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Construação")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> ConstructionDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Condomínio")]
    public string CondominiumType { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}-\d{3}$", ErrorMessage = "CEP está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "CEP")]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    public string District { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UF")]
    public string Uf { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Número")]
    public Nullable<int> Number { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Complemento")]
    public string Complement { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Observação")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EmailViewModel> Emails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PhoneViewModel> Phones { get; set; }

    public BankViewModel Banks { get; set; }
}

public class EmailViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Email está em um formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Telefone ou Celular")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\([1-9]{2}\) (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Telefone ou Celular estão em um formato inválido.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class BankViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Banco")]
    public string Bank { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Agência")]
    public Nullable<int> Agency { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Conta Corrente")]
    public Nullable<int> AccountCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddCondominiumViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Saberiam me auxiliar no que estou fazendo errado, pois estou sempre recebendo os dados de telefone como um Count = 0 ?

Comment: cadê o endpoint que recebe a informação do formulario?

Comment: Ele carrega um model atrás da ViewModel que coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Apresente a action da sua controller

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, adicionei meu `controller` na pergunta;

Comment: @LucasMiranda ..

Comment: Na verdade o ideal seria uma tabela separada com as informações e um campo fk que vai ligar o contato com o cliente, ou seja la a tabela que tu vai linkar

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo isso. Mas preciso receber os dados de vários telefones na ViewModel para poder inserir nas tabelas

Comment: A model está completamente vazia ou apenas a lista de telefones?

Comment: Apenas o telefone e email. Eles ficam com Count = 0;

Comment: Verifica se o teu front está enviando as propriedades Emails e Phones como arrays para que ocorra a conversão pra lista.

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma, mas continuo não recebendo.

Comment: Quando esse input `<input type="text" class="form-control phone" asp-for="Phones" placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">` é rederizado no navegador, como fica o `id` ou `name` dele?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93416/discussion-between-gustavoadolfo-and-matheus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você cria campos dinamicamente e por isso o name="NomeCampo" não é reconhecido pela controller.

Lembre-se que ao fazer um asp-for="Model.Propriedade" vc está apenas fazendo uma atalho pra:

```
value="@Model.Propriedade"
name="Propriedade"
```

Existe 3 maneiras de fazer, vou explicar 2:

**1. Usando o componente BeginCollection** - Melhor opção!

instale o pacote:

```
Install-Package BeginCollectionItemCore -Version 1.0.8
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItemCore/

(caso não for o asp.net core procure o pacote correto)
Ajuda detalhada para fazer:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Um demo totalmente funcional você encontra em:
https://github.com/saad749/BeginCollectionItemCore/tree/master/BeginCollectionItemCoreDemo
Coloque um breackPoint na controller e entenda o funcionamento.

**2. Recuperando os name na 'unha'**

No javascript você vai criar um campo dinamicamente, com o name do tipo

```
name="Telefone_1"

public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] form)
{
var Tel1 = Request.Form["Telefone_1"];

}
```

E assim para cada campo, você pode enviar um campo hidden para saber a qtd. de campos.
Mas recomendo novamente, utilizar o Begin Collection.
Caso tenha alguma dúvida com ele abra uma nova pergunta.